# Automate the Boring Stuff Coin Flip Streaks Problem

Tags: python

I think I got the right answer but I'm just starting out, so would take any helpful criticism on things I can do to be more efficient or mistakes I may have made. Specifically I didn't know how to compare 6 in a row without comparing them individually, which I realize is not efficient. Appreciate you taking a look! Ref: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter4/

```
import random, sys
numberOfStreaks = 0
def countstreaks(coinFlipList):
    numberOfStreaks=0
    i=1
    while i<9995:
        if coinFlipList[i-1] == coinFlipList[i] == coinFlipList[i+1] == coinFlipList[i+2] == coinFlipList[i+3] == coinFlipList[i+4]:
            numberOfStreaks += 1
            i += 1
        else:
            i += 1
            continue
    print(numberOfStreaks)
    print('Chance of streak: %s%%' % (numberOfStreaks / 100))

coinFlipList=[]
for i in range(10000):
    if random.randint(0,1) == 0:
        coinFlipList.append('H')
    else:
        coinFlipList.append('T')

countstreaks(coinFlipList)
```

Tried the code block above. Got a result of 337 streaks for a probability of 3.37%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does seem to give the correct resulting (assuming a sequence of 7 is two sequences of 6).
However, there is no need to repeatedly access and compare the same List elements. It is more
efficient just to go through the List once and count character sequences. Code below shows that change and is
tidied to 1. Use Python convention naming (variable_name) 2. Use changeable constants for the sizes
3. Use a more modern f-string to print 4. Using random_choice (note there is no point in generating random
0 and 1 and then changing to 'H' and 'T' - the code would work with 0, 1 anyway). 5. Using different name for local
and global variable (flip_list, coin_flip_List)

It would not be much more effort to collect counts of the various run sequences and store these in a dictionary.

```
import random
SIZE = 10000
SEQ = 6

def count_streaks(flip_list):
    number_of_streaks = 0
    previous = ''
    count = 0
    for x in flip_list:
        if x == previous:
            count += 1
        else:
             count = 1
        if count >= SEQ:
            number_of_streaks += 1
        previous = x

    print(f"{number_of_streaks} Chance of streak {number_of_streaks*100/SIZE}%")
        
coin_flip_list=[]

for i in range(SIZE):
    coin_flip_list.append(random.choice(['H', 'T']))

count_streaks(coin_flip_list)
```

Comment: thanks so much for the answer -- that's a much better way to solve the same problem and was exactly the kind of feedback I was hoping for as I continue to try to learn. When I saw count >= SEQ: number of streaks += 1 I thought it wouldn't count distinct 6 streaks if it was like 9 in a row that would be 4 distinct streaks (1-6, 2-7 etc) but realized each time it loops it would count it so that's awesome and really clever. Also I don't think I've learned about "f-string" printing yet -- would you mind sharing with me why that's best practice? Thank you!

Comment: fstrings are simoly a very flexible way to form strings - not only for printing. See [link](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). As regards code in general: whenever I see repeated code (such as your List element comparisons) then I look for a more concise, clearer approach.